# C#: Add strings to an array if the array does not contain the string

Tags: c#

I have a lot of string arrays. From all these string arrays, I want to create an array of unique strings. At the moment I do it like this:

```
string[] strings = {};

while(running)
{
   newStringArrayToAdd[] = GetStrings();
   strings = strings.Concat(newStringArrayToAdd).ToArray();
}

uniqueStrings = strings.Distinct.ToArray();
```

This works but it is very very slow since I have to keep the strings variable in memory which gets very huge. Therefore I'm looking for a way to check on the fly if a string is in uniqueStrings and if not add it immediately. How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use, StringBuilder?

Comment: Is it an option to add all strings to a `HashSet`?

Comment: Just to clarify... your input is an array or arrays? and your desired output is a single unique array?

Comment: my input are arrays and i want a single array.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException you better show more code of how to you get the input so that the answers are better

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider using a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead of an array. It will do nothing if the string already exists in the set:

```
HashSet<string> strings = new HashSet<string>();

strings.Add("foo");
strings.Add("foo");

strings.Count // 1
```

The [`UnionWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097.aspx) method will be very useful in your example code:

```
HashSet<string> strings = new HashSet<string>();

while(running)
{
   string[] newStringArrayToAdd = GetStrings();
   strings.UnionWith(newStringArrayToAdd);
}
```

Comment: However, then I need an additional loop for that?

Comment: Thanks I used this one and copied the hashset back to a string array afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [HashSet](http://www.google.pl/#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=9183db743a37969e&q=hashset+c#) instead. Like this:

```
HashSet<string> uniqueStrings = new HashSet<string>();

for loop...
if (!uniqueStrings.Contains(newStringToAdd))
{
  uniqueStrings.Add(newStringToAdd);
}
```

To get the array afterwards:

```
var uniqueStringArray = uniqueStrings.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you keep a list of the hashes of the strings?

When adding a new string, if its hash is not already in the list, you know its unique.

If the hash is present it *could* be unique, or it might be a hash-collision, so you have to check the long way.  But that should be a relatively rare case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Union`

```
string[] result = strings.Union(strings2).ToArray();
```

Thus change your code as

```
string[] strings = {};

while(running)
{
   newStringArrayToAdd[] = GetStrings();
   strings = strings.Union(newStringArrayToAdd).ToArray();
}

// No need for this line as strings will be unique
//uniqueStrings = strings.Distinct.ToArray();
```

As per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx)

> This method excludes duplicates from the return set. This is different behavior to the Concat method, which returns all the elements in the input sequences including duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Hashset` that will do the filtering for you:

```
HashSet<string> strings = new HashSet<string>();

for loop....
  foreach (string s in newStringArrayToAdd)
    strings.Add(s);
end of loop:

uniqueStrings = strings.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `HashSet<string>`.  Here is more information on how lists work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing the strings in a HashSet rather than an array? The hashset will guarantee uniqueness in constant time every time you add to it.

```
var strings = new HashSet<string>();
strings.Add("abc");
strings.Add("abc");
strings.Count // is 1
```